# Datepicker angular directive for Bootstrap not showing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my Angular project I am trying to use the Angular directives for bootstrap [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), but it isn't showing up.

I've linked to `<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>` and
`<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>` in my *index.html* and in my *app.js* I've put `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency.

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

I am trying to use `uib-datepicker-popup` within a ng-switch within a ng-repeat, but I don't see why that would cause any problem:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in vm.fields">
    <label for="{{ field.propertyName }}">
        <h5><span translate="{{ field.translate }}"></span>
            <span class="form-control-required" ng-show="{{field.required}}">*</span>
        </h5>
    </label>
    <div ng-switch="field.type" ng-class="{ 'input-group': field.type === 'date' }">
        <select ng-switch-when="gender"
                name="{{ field.propertyName }}" id="{{ field.propertyName }}"
                ng-model="vm.model[field.propertyName]" class="form-control"
                ng-required="{{ field.required }}">
            <option value="m">Male</option>
            <option value="f">Female</option>
        </select>
        <textarea ng-switch-when="textarea"
                  name="{{ field.propertyName }}" id="{{ field.propertyName }}"
                  class="form-control" ng-model="vm.model[field.propertyName]"
                  ng-required="{{ field.required }}"></textarea>
        <input ng-switch-when="date"
               type="date" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" 
               show-weeks="false" is-open="vm.datePickerOpen"
               name="{{ field.propertyName }}" id="{{ field.propertyName }}"
               class="form-control pull-left" ng-model="vm.model[field.propertyName]"
               ng-required="{{ field.required }}">
        <span class="input-group-btn btn-" ng-if="field.type === 'date'">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                    ng-click="vm.openDatePicker($event)">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
        <input ng-switch-default=""
               type="{{ field.type }}" name="{{ field.propertyName }}" id="{{ field.propertyName }}"
               class="form-control pull-left" ng-model="vm.model[field.propertyName]"
               ng-required="{{ field.required }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
vm.datePickerOpen = false;

vm.openDatePicker = function($event) {
    vm.datePickerOpen = true;
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apperently the documentation on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker is for a newer version. By changing `uib-datepicker-popup` to `datepicker-popup` it worked.

Also I had to change `<input type="date" datepicker-popup>` to `<input type="text" datepicker-popup>` because of this: [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

It is working now. The documentation on Angular directives for bootstrap should mention from what version to use the uib-datepicker and where datepicker is applicable.

Comment: After some more searching I found this migration guide and know now that the prefix change to add uib- is **from release 0.14.0** : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer. I'm a bit confused by this control. For me it is working using <input type="text" datepicker-popup> and not the other way around. Which is inconsistent with the documentation??? So long as it works I guess that is the main thing!

Comment: @cyoung Check which version of UI Bootstrap you are running. The uib- prefix was introduced inversion 0.14.0. So you are probably running an older version.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue.
After 2 hours of digging and trying, I was able to make it work with an

`<input type=text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="user.birthday" />`

only by making the model data a Date object in the controller

like this

```
//after we fetch the model (user) data make the needed field a Date object
user.birthday = new Date(user.birthday);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those searching, I had the same issue, this fixed my issue. Added [AngularMoment to my module](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) and Injected "moment":

```
$scope.object.moment = moment();
$scope.object.date = $scope.object.moment.toDate();
```

then:

```
<datepicker ng-model="object.date"></datepicker>
```